# hover event change to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div that when hovered flips over, rotates3d 180 degrees.

Its all working well. But I want it so that instead of flipping when hovered, I want to be able to call the event in javascript, so for example the div flips on page load.

here is the css for the hover..

```
#flipDiv:hover .flipDivIn {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
}
```

Comment: Its very simple add flip class and trigger add class on trigger of this event

Answer (score 1):

You can define a CSS class which rotates an element, and dynamically add/remove this class with JavaScript. For example:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var btn = document.getElementById('button');
var re = /\bflip\b/g;

// you can add this listener to any DOM event
function flip() {

  // if element has class "flip"
  if (re.test(div.className)) {

    // remove class "flip"
    div.className = div.className.replace(re, '');
  } else {

    // otherwise add class "flip"
    div.className += ' flip';
  }
}

// for demo purposes, flip on button click
btn.addEventListener('click', flip, false);
```

```css
#div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgray;

  /* optionally, add a transition in order to animate the flip */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
.flip {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="div">Hello!</div>
<button id="button">Flip!</button>
```

---

Note that if you are using jQuery, the JS code above can be vastly simplified:

```
var $btn = $('#btn'),
    $div = $('#div');
$btn.on('click', function () {
    $div.toggleClass('flip');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with a fiddle, I added a transition effect to your flip code for fun:

https://jsfiddle.net/edencorbin/sLz15ves/

html:

```
    <div id="flipdiv">
    <img id="flipdiv" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
```

javascript

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    flipDiv();

    function flipDiv() {
      $('#flipdiv').addClass('flipDivIn');
    };
    });
```

css

```
    .flipDivIn {
      -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
      transition: 1s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
      transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is on page load https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/dzx37chb/

html

```
<body onload="rotate()">


<div id="someDiv">
<h1>blah blah blah</h1>
</div>
</body>
<script>
function rotate(){
document.getElementById("someDiv").className = "flipDivIn";
}
</script>
```

css

```
div{background-color: blue;}
.flipDivIn {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that:

**Option 1. CSS + JS**

**CSS (class not to be applied beforehand)**

```
.flipDivIn {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
}
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('#flipDiv').addEventListener(event,function(e){
   e.currentTarget.className += 'flipDivIn';
});
```

**Option 2. JS only**

```
document.getElementById('#flipDiv').addEventListener(event,function(e){
   var tS = e.currentTarget.style;
   tS.WebkitTransform = tS.MozTransform = tS.transform = 'rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg)';
});
```

The keyword `event` will be replaced by the event of your choice (e.g. `'click'`).

If you want to use an event on another tag, than use this:

```
anyElement.addEventListener(event,function(){
   var tS = document.getElementById('#flipDiv').style;
   tS.WebkitTransform = tS.MozTransform = tS.transform = 'rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg)';
});
```